# Alternatives to storing data in an NSMutableArray which makes searching easier

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Advice much greatly needed,

I am developing an app that i wish to temporarily store data locally,

Currently i have created my own class filling the class and putting the data into a NSMutableArray.

Example:

```
            ExampleClass *_exampleClass = [[ExampleClass alloc]init];
            [_exampleClass setID: 1];
            [_exampleClass setPara1: @"AAA"];
            [_exampleClass setPara2: @"BBB"];
            [_exampleClass setPara3: @"CCC"];

            [List addObject: _exampleClass];


 *List being a NSMutableArray
```

At other points in the app i then display this list.

```
             ExampleClass *_exampleClass = [List objectAtIndex:0];
             _exampleClass.Para1.....
```

Only issue is in a lot of cases i have to filter what is displayed so for example display List where Para1 != @"AAA" for example. Having this is a NSMutableArray makes it really messy, i just wondered if there was a cleaner simpler way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Core Data with an in memory store? The way it looks, your queries are complex enough to worth the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can just use `NSPredicate` to filter your array. You can use `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` to make a new array from an existing one, filtered by the predicate. You can use `-[NSMutableArray filterUsingPredicate:]` to filter a mutable array in place, removing objects which don't match the predicate.

If you use array controllers to help manage your UI, you can directly assign to the `filterPredicate` property to have them filter what is shown. You can also bind that property to another controller's property.

A predicate which represents your example (Para1 != @"AAA") is pretty straightforward:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Para1 != 'AAA'"];
```

You should also familiarize yourself with the various `...PassingTest:` methods of `NSArray`, such as `-indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`. It doesn't get much easier or more powerful than that.